How to Load properties file in Flink
I know I can pass application parameters via args or -D, but I would like to have the configuration in the specified properties file and have different flink applications use different properties files.
And I want the application to run in application (e.g. yarn-applicaion) mode, is there a way for Flink to upload this profile from the local file system and make it readable by the application.
So how to Load properties file in Flink?
